# How can I get same session in labstack echo session middleware?

Tags: go, session, go-echo

Is there the missing config or something else?
The main config:

[image]

The Request handlers:

[image: request handlers]

Comment: Please avoid posting images.

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question

Comment: Hi, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/session)

> Session middleware facilitates HTTP session management backed by
>   [gorilla/sessions](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions). The default implementation provides cookie and
>   filesystem based session store; however, you can take advantage of
>   community maintained implementation for various backends.

It stores a cookie for the session. Your question is very basic. Not sure if this is what you are needing.